# Tablesorter filter gets error when calling length method on table.config.cache.row

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, tablesorter

I am working with RoR application and trying to implement fulltext search for jquery-tablesorter

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BCreb/104/

Everything work great in jsfiddle, but when i set it to application and try to write to search box, browser screams:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

It's in file **jquery.tablesorter.filter.mod.js:120**

```
    var allRows = table.config.cache.row;
    var resultRows = [];

    var allRowsCount = allRows.length;  <-- here is line 120
```

I can't figure it out, why am i getting this error. Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure to have the latest version of tablesorter? It seemds (here: http://www.tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js ) that the line 120 is not the same and the computing is different.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like your demo is using v2.0.3 and the one at tablesorter.com is v2.0.5. Have you tried any other filter plugins, something like this one works well: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

Comment: gem tablesorter is uptodate, addon filter is downloaded from page, latest of course ... I am happy with this solution, but if i will be unable to resolve it, i'll try something else.

Comment: You could also try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)

Comment: I just switched to datatables, imho better solution.